# WM_COPYDATA without a class in Delphi

Tags: delphi, wm-copydata

I would like to send / receive a string from 2 CONSOLE Applications (2 different PIDs with no Forms!). I saw that I need the declare this in a class. Is it possible to do this without having a class at all in a console application? If so, how I can do that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just have a look at WM from WM_COPYDATA, it's build from WindowMessage. So it is in fact a Message sent to a Window. But not only a TForm is a Window. Nearly everything you can see on your display is based on a window. Thats why MS called their product Windows ;o)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use `WM_COPYDATA` without a window to send it to.  If you don't use classes, you will have to use the Win32 API `RegisterClass()` and `CreateWindow/Ex()` functions directly to allocate a window and provide your own stand-alone function for its message handler procedure.

But why not use classes?  Then you can leverage the RTL's built-in message handler systems.  At the very least, you can use `AllocateHWnd()` with a static class method so you don't have to instantiate a class object at runtime, eg:

```
type
  TWindowMessages = class
  public
    class procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
  end;

class procedure TWindowMessages.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  //...
end;

var
  Wnd: HWND;

Wnd := AllocateHWnd(TWindowMessages.WndProc);
// pump the message queue for new messages as needed...
DeallocateHWnd(Wnd);
```

If this does not suit your needs, then you should consider a different IPC mechanism that does not rely on windows, such as named pipes, mailslots, sockets, etc.

Comment: Minor nit-pick. That's not a static class method. A static class method has no implicit Self parameter. You make a static class method by adding static to the end of the declaration. That's a class method.